# how protect my files in APK?

Tags: apk

i have made a quiz app, and stored the questions  and assures in a text file. I found the APK file can be easily unpacked and you can see all the files in it.
Is there a way to protect them?

Comment: You can you sqlite database with sqlcipher instead of testfile

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use sqlite for store data. 
[Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
Good tutorial here ([Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/))

And you can decrypt your sqlite database with [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)